How to pass props through outlet context and retrieve props from useOutletContext() inside child component
I try to use context inside Outlet react-dom-router component and retrieve props through useOutletContext() inside outlet children component as below
tsx // inside parent component
<Outlet
context={[
purchaseData,
setPurchaseData,
catsData,
setCatsData,
isLoading,
setIsLoading,
affection,
setAffection,
affectionColor,
setAffectionColor,
setHeaderBackgroundColor,
]}
/>`
 tsx
//inside outlet children components: const { purchaseData, setPurchaseData, catsData, setCatsData, isLoading, setIsLoading, affection, setAffection, affectionColor, setAffectionColor, setHeaderBackgroundColor, } = useOutletContext();
`
The problem is that if the pattern of context from both parent and children is not match. The props retrieved are not matched despite the fact that they have the same names. I tried to console.log(useOutletContext() and it turns out to not recognize the names from parent props). Hence when retrieving props inside children components is completely based on order of the props provided and retrieved.
Is there away to fix this issue or retrieve context based on name instead of order?
I tried to retrieve and pass  props based on name through outlet context and useOutletContext hook from react-dom-router. what i was expected: data is matched based on name. What was happened: data is not matched based on name but matched based on order. Therefore, The app was crashed if there is a minor difference between order of passed context and retrieved context.

You should consume the context value the same way it is provided.
If using an array:
<Outlet
  context={[
    purchaseData,
    setPurchaseData,
    catsData,
    setCatsData,
    isLoading,
    setIsLoading,
    affection,
    setAffection,
    affectionColor,
    setAffectionColor,
    setHeaderBackgroundColor
  ]}
/>

Then consumers should use array destructuring assignment to access the values they want. Order matter since you are accessing array elements
const [
  purchaseData,
  setPurchaseData,
  catsData,
  setCatsData,
  isLoading,
  setIsLoading,
  affection,
  setAffection,
  affectionColor,
  setAffectionColor,
  setHeaderBackgroundColor
] = useOutletContext();

or if you only wanted a subset, i.e. only isLoading and setHeaderBackgroundColor:
const [,,,, isLoading,,,,,, setHeaderBackgroundColor] = useOutletContext();

Using an object would make partially consuming the values since it removes the order requirement. Simply use object destructuring assignment.
<Outlet
  context={{
    purchaseData,
    setPurchaseData,
    catsData,
    setCatsData,
    isLoading,
    setIsLoading,
    affection,
    setAffection,
    affectionColor,
    setAffectionColor,
    setHeaderBackgroundColor
  }}
/>

const { setHeaderBackgroundColor, isLoading } = useOutletContext();


Thank you a lot. I didn't know that there is a difference between using an object vs using an array for context.  So if i understand it correctly, using object is better and safer that using an array for context? Is there a case that we use an array over an object for passing and retrieve data through context?

@Captain_Turtle That's a little subjective, but IMO I tend to prefer objects over arrays for Context values (and also custom hooks, for the same reason) because of the destructuring differences. I'd say there's likely a case to be made for using an array if the usage requires all array elements to be used, a.k.a. like the useState hook returns an array [state, stateSetter], or useReducer returns an array [state, dispatchFunction]. Does this makes sense and help clarify?

@Captain_Turtle Also, and not to confuse you at all, arrays are objects where the index is the key, which is why the object property accessor works for arrays, e.g. arr[1]. Imagine you had an array foo = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"], you could use object destructuring like let { 0: foo1, 2: foo2 } = foo to get foo1 ("foo") and foo2 ("foobar"), but note here that you still need to be aware of the array element order to access via the correct key. Using plain objects is just a little easier to work with.

@Captain_Turtle Did this sufficiently address your question(s)/concern(s)?
